# PSfrag comparable package / method for XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, psfrag

I am compiling my TeX files using `XeLaTeX`. I have created a lot of EPS files using MATLAB. However, the text and math fonts are not consistent.

Unfortunately the PSfrag package is not compatible with XeLaTeX. I am looking for a package or method comparable to `\psfrag` to replace some tags in the EPS figures when compiling with `XeLaTeX`.

Example:

```
\begin{figure}
\psfrag{yyyy}{\small{$y$}}
\includegraphics{dummy.eps}
\end{figure}
```

Anyone who knows a very simple workaround for this?

Comment: Do you know about the `psfragx` package and its `LaPrint` matlab script? It might be helpful.

Comment: Could you provide an example please?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have Matlab and don't know how to use it. My comment was only a suggestion. Maybe someone will have a more useful idea.